# Connection Arduino with ROS

Tags: rosinstall, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Folks,

I have a problem in the connection between arduino and ROS, I am using Ubuntu 15, 64 bit, Jade version ROS.

The problem in these two following commands commands

> > roscd rosserial_arduino/src
> > cp -r ros_lib /libraries/ros_lib

It gives the following error

> > bash: /libraries/ros_lib: No such file or directory

Although I have tried to download the source code from Github and putting in the sketchbook of Arduino Linux environment, but no connection.

Another concern between Catkin and Rosbuild, I have read difference between them, but uptill now I can't figure out if the problem lies in selecting the proper for building executive files.
Any recommendation!

Have a Great Day!

Best,
Marwa ELDiwiny

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247288/connection-arduino-with-ros/) by [marwa eldiwiny](https://answers.ros.org/users/27638/marwa-eldiwiny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-11-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks, I have figure out the problem. But I don't understand why removing dot  could cause a problem

$ rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py .

---

Originally posted by [marwa eldiwiny](https://answers.ros.org/users/27638/marwa-eldiwiny/) with karma: 51 on 2016-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-11-05**:
`.` is the current working directory.